# Command Option P R not working with Bootcamp installed

Tags: macos, nvram

I have an error 43 when trying to delete a folder in Mac OS - I have read that to fix this I need to reset the NVRAM - to do that I need to boot with <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> - however, this makes the startup noise continually until I release the buttons.

So far so good, but when I do release (I tried after 2 and after 3 startup sounds) - it just boots directly into Windows.

How can I make this work?

Comment: In what context are you seeing "error 43"?  That's entirely too vague.

Comment: It also seems to be something of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: What do you mean with "make it work"? Which result do you expect?

Comment: I want to boot with command option p r - but it keeps booting into windows rather than booting into mac os when I do it. So I want to get command option p r to work when bootcamp is installed.

Comment: I get error 43 when trying to delete a folder.

Comment: You don't boot *with* Cmd-Opt-P-R, that's used to reset the NVRAM. Period  See my answer to boot into macOS.  I am assuming you are attempting to delete a folder in *Windows* and getting "error 43".  *Which version of Windows?  Keep in mind - we are not there to look over your shoulder.  **It's essential you describe what you are doing, how you're doing it and in what environment.**

Comment: ahh - i thought cmd opt pr booted into some kind of safe mode. No I'm not even accessing that folder in Windows. In the end I just used Onyx to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the NVRAM won't make your Mac boot into OS X, which is what I am assuming you want to do.

What you need to do is hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key when booting and then select the macOS partition as your startup.

If you want to boot into macOS from Windows directly, you have to right click the Bookcamp icon and select "Restart in OS X"

[image]

For more info, please see [Apple's Bootcamp Documentation](https://help.apple.com/bootcamp/controlpanel/6.1/#/bcmp1c70f878)

Comment: No I want to reset the NVRAM because I have an error 43, as I said in the question?!

That tip about restarting in OS X is very useful though thx.